# Alamofire request from outside ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire

Is there any way to call request by alamofire from outside the ViewController (UITableViewController) and then populate tablewView with data from response? right now I'm created a func inside the controller and after fetching the data just call tablewView's reloadData(). But is there any way to create method like this:

```
class InsuranceServices {

    class func getContracts(table : UITableView) -> [Contract] {
        var contracts = [Contract]()
        let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        ]
        let params : Parameters = [String:Any]()

        Alamofire.request("http://test:9090/testService/getContracts", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response -> Void in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                for data in json["data"].arrayValue {
                    let contract = Contract(json: data)
                    print(contract.fullName!)
                    contracts.append(contract)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            table.reloadData()
        })
        return contracts
    }

}
```

this method is not working for me. maybe there is another way? I think create service methods inside the controller is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have distinct separation between your `ViewController` and `Alamofire`.
A way to achieve that is similar to what you wrote, but instead of taking the `UITableView` itself, your function should take a completion block that receives `[Contract]`.

It can look something like this:

```
class func getContracts(completion: @escaping ([Contract])→Void) { 
    //...
    Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON(completionHandler: {response -> Void in

        switch response.result {

        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            var contracts = [Contract]()
            for data in json["data"].arrayValue {
                let contract = Contract(json: data)
                contracts.append(contract)                    
            }
            completion(contracts)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion([])
        }
    })
}
```

Another thing is that you can't return the result of the request (in your case array of `Contract`) in the return value of the function. Since `Alamofire` call the request asynchronously it would end much later than the return of your function. That is why as you see the function signature I wrote does not return anything. Instead, it calls the `completion` closure when the request is ready and the data is available.

Note that you *must* call the `completion` closure even on failure! Otherwise the caller (in your case your view controller) will wait for the request forever not knowing it failed....

You can then call the function like so, making sure you don't cause a memory leak with `self`:

```
InsuranceServices.getContracts(completionHandler: { [weak self] data in 
    self?.contracts = data
    self?.tableView.reloadData() 
})
```

Comment: Og my God, I completely forget about @escaping. in Controller side I called this func in this way:
InsuranceServices.getContracts(completionHandler: {data in
            self.contracts = data
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }) and it's worked. thx a lot!

Comment: Since it is `@escaping` like you mentioned, you should avoid holding on to `self`. Imagine a situation where you dismissed the view controller and only later the request returns - self would than stay in memory even though you dismissed the screen. To avoid that you should hold a `weak` reference to self. I edited my answer with the call...